# NLog upgrade issue

Tags: nlog

I have a micro service nad using Nlog, I upgraded my Nlog (NLog.Web.AspNetCore) from 4.8.5 to 5.3.8, and run my micro service, I am getting this error: System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,NLog.Layouts.SimpleLayout> NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration.get_Variables()'.', any ideas?

Build is fine, but could not run the webhost.

Answer (score 0):

NLog v5 contains [several breaking changes](https://nlog-project.org/2021/08/25/nlog-5-0-preview1-ready.html). One of them is changing NLog Configuration Variables to support any Layout (Ex. JsonLayout instead only SimpleLayout).

You should look at the StackTrace from the `System.MissingMethodException`, and use it to pin-point the project that needs explicit upgrade to NLog v5.